# How to change the text of a button using databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding

This should be simple, but I am running into problems.  I'm trying to change the text of a button depending on whether the list is in descending or ascending order.  This is what I have:

> In my view model:

```
fun ascendingDescending() {
    if (ascendingOrDescending == AscendDescend.ASC) {
        ascendingOrDescending = AscendDescend.DESC
        isAscend = false
    } else {
        ascendingOrDescending = AscendDescend.ASC
        isAscend = true
    }

    val searchAndSort = searchQuery.value
    searchAndSort?.ascendDescend = ascendingOrDescending
    searchQuery.postValue(searchAndSort)

}
```

> In my .xml file:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAscendDescend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnFilterBy"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnSortBy"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        android:text="@{viewModel.isAscend ? @string/work_packages_descend : @string/work_packages_ascend}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.ascendingDescending()}"
        />
```

When I click the button, the text is not changing from Descending to Ascending.

Comment: What exactly is `viewModel`? If it is literally a `ViewModel`/`AndroidViewModel`, it is not intrinsically observable. If you want your binding expressions to be evaluated as data changes, data binding needs to know about the changes. This is why I usually have my `ViewModel` hold a `LiveData<ViewState>`, where `ViewState` is a `data` class holding the stuff for the binding expressions. My `<variable>` is the `LiveData<ViewState>`, and data binding will know how to observe that (if you call `setLifecycleObserver()`). There are other options, but in the end, it has to be observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add please `binding.lifecycleOwner = this` exactly after you create the binding.
And also make sur to make `isAscend` as MutableLiveData.

Answer (score 0):

in xml file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"                        
                    android:text='@={loginViewModel.loginText}' />
```

in viewModel

```
  var loginText = ObservableField("Login")      
    if(phoneNumber.length>1){    
    loginText.set(context.getString(R.string.getOtp))          
    }    
    else{    
     loginText.set(context.getString(R.string.login))    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you've created the binding, initialize the lifecycleOwner and viewModel for the two way binding in the fragment.

```
binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
binding.viewModel = viewModel
```

Assuming you of course have set the correct properties in the gradle files.